# How to create a grid in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple grid that is uniform. For some reason, my grid has this weird spacing between rows. Here is my grid so far:

[image]

I am creating a grid like so:

```
const grid = [];
for (let row = 0; row < GRID_ROW_LENGTH; row++) {
  const currentRow = [];
  for (let col = 0; col < GRID_COL_LENGTH; col++) {
    currentRow.push(newNode);
  }
    grid.push(currentRow);
}
```

Where node is just some data and is considered each cell in the grid. The node is simply wrapped in a div with the class name .node

Node Class returns:

```
<div
  className="node"
></div>
```

node.css

```
  .node {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: white;
      outline: 1px solid rgba(144, 175, 175, 0.75);
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

I display the grid like so:

```
<div className="grid">
  {grid.map((row, rowId) => {
    return (
      <div key={rowId}>
        {row.map((node, nodeId) => {
          return (
            <Node></Node>
          );
   })}
</div>`
```

grid.css

```
.grid {
  text-align: center;
}
```

How do I get rid of that spacing between my rows? Also, is there any way to make this grid somewhat responsive to the size of the webpage?

Comment: If you open the inspector in your browser, are there non-zero padding/margin/borders present in the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces appears because of the `inline-block` layout.
There are some technics how to get rid of it.
But I would say the most proper way to create a grid is using `display: flex` or `display: grid`

Comment: Yup this is a good direction to go for this. 
I'd recommend you check out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: When I change it, I just get a verticle line of cells down the page...

Comment: The easiest way in your case is to set `font-size: 0` to the `.grid` class. But don't forget to restore it if you are going to have text in cells

Comment: the font-size did it, would have never gotten that, thanks